# how to make a realistic sugar cube material?

Tags: materials, shaders

I have been struggling with this for a while, and can't figure out help. I would like to make a realistic sugar cube material procedural, but so far I couldn't manage to get a satisfactory result, can you please help me improve it? 
My render i know it looks like solid object not translucency or sss but I do applied both with an add noder can be seen in the [file](http://www.pasteall.org/blend/37518)

[image]

I m seeking a solution to make shiny sprinkle looking small parts and translucency of main shader. I can't figure out how though.

thanks

EDIT- second render after @PGmath suggested note set up which helped a lot to get a much more better result, however I wish there was some way to reduce the noise , even with 300 samples there are plenty noise, is it normal?

[image]

Comment: You have to add subsurface scattering

Comment: Hi @IgorTatarnikov thanks for suggestion but it already has sss and translucency with add shader node, but surely something wrong which doesn't make it look like sss applied

Comment: @ideorium Could you please post your material nodes set up?

Comment: For starters I would use a voronoi texture set to *cells* as a normal map.

Comment: Ok, I have added the blend file @Gonzou alternatively you can download it [here](http://www.pasteall.org/blend/37518) too

Answer (score 8):

Here's what i have come up with after a few minutes of playing around.

[image]

The entire shader is based on cell voronoi textures.  Voronoi works well for this kind of thing because it gives nice pixel-like results.  The actual geometry is just a massively subdivided cube with a displace modifier using a small voronoi texture.

[image]

Here are the shader nodes:
[image]
<sub>Click to enlarge</sub>

It's basically a huge mix of diffuse, gloss, SSS, glass, and translucency; with a small amount of volume scattering (to simulate the light bouncing around on the sugar grains inside the cube).  Everything uses a single voronoi texture as a normal map, each shader uses a different level of bump though.  It could definitely use some tweaking, but it's a pretty good start.

### A note on speed/noise:

---

First of all you have to realize that things like rough gloss, SSS and translucency will all generate a good deal of noise, meaning you need more samples.  I would suggest at least 500 samples for rendering many of these.  That said, there are a couple things that you can do to cut render times, and less render time means you can afford more samples.

First of all you can probably get away with nixing the volumetrics.  Though accurate it isn't essential to use the volume scatter, this alone cut my render time almost in half.

Second you can add these nodes at the end:
[image]

What this is doing is only making it compute all those complicated shaders for glossy and camera rays (the add node works like a logical OR), for all other rays it just computes diffuse.  I use this trick all the time in indoor scenes especially.

Comment: Very nice result! Increasing the Scale of the Subsurface Scatering node may make it even better.

Comment: wow thanks a lot for your answer, I will study the node setup asap which looks very interesting and informative @PGmath thanks

Comment: @PGmath , I have applied the shader node set up with some little changes and object geometry with displacement, here is the [result](http://imgur.com/UrLrrN7) it had so much noise even with 300 render samples, I am wondering how can I make it less noisy with less render samples.. thanks

Comment: @ideorium check out this guide: http://www.blenderguru.com/articles/7-ways-get-rid-fireflies/ May be very helpful.

Comment: @ideorium You could try nixing the volume scatter, it adds something but it's not much.  In my render I also disabled caustics, if you have other things in your scene which need caustics this might not be an option, but trying to render caustics on this thing is really a nightmare.  I have one other idea I will try, I'll add it to the answer if it works.  But honestly, for a shader like this you're going to need more than 300 samples, things like SSS, translucency, and rough gloss need a lot of sampling.

Comment: @PGmath , first of all shall I upload my new renders here or in the original body text of question? this is 500 samples with and with volumetrics, it does reduces slightly the noises when not using volumetric as shown [here](http://imgur.com/33Nf5Vf) , and I also applied the new node group you mentioned to add at the end as [here](http://imgur.com/mPZHNa5)  it did help with the noise and speed indeed, but kinda makes cubes go darker and look like dirtier.  About the scene: I will be using these sugar cubes in a scene where couple of glass and other transparent and reflective surfaces will be

Comment: @PGmath , i'd also would like to know where as your extra node group can be use, you mentioned in door scenes, can you give an example more specific of its used material? thanks

Comment: @ideorium The nodes highlighted in red are what I was talking about, just stick that at the end of any shader tree and change the color of the diffuse shader to fit the material.